# Where do I obtain wevutil?

Tags: windows, utility

I've read many articles about using wevutil.exe and it seems to be exactly what I need.  However, I cannot find it.  I've tried on a Windows 2003 server, Windows 2008 server, Windows 7, etc.  All come back with "'wevutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command".  TechNet (which has docs on using it) doesn't list a download point so I assume it is provided with Windows?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean **wevtutil**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you just misspelled, it's actually **WevtUtil**, and is located in `C:\Windows\System32`.